# If my rental property income and mortgage payment are equal, do I need to pay income tax on any rent revenue?

Tags: income-tax, canada, tax-deduction, rental-property, ontario

Let's say I have a monthly mortgage payment of $1600 on a condo I own, and the condo is rented out for $1600. Then, I'm breaking even. Hence, I would not need to pay any tax on my rental income. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally incorrect.

Some of your mortgage payment is interest, and some is repayment of principal. When it comes to deducting your rental property's expenses against its income, you generally aren't permitted to deduct the repayment of loan principal.

So, no, $1600 rent and $1600 mortgage payment (ignoring all else) is not break-even — rather, you are profiting to the extent that your rental property's mortgage principal is being reduced. That profit is taxable income, even if your cash flow hasn't benefited. Otherwise, you could "break even" this way in perpetuity and at the end of the mortgage have a property paid for fully in tax-free dollars! Nope.

(I said "generally" at top because the possibility of an interest-only loan does make the entire payment interest, but I mention this merely for completeness and not because it is likely to apply.)

Comment: I was writing a response, but Chris's covers most of my points, and is accurate. http://blog.turbotax.ca/what-expenses-can-you-claim-on-a-rental-property-part-3/ covers what you can and cannot deduct, and points out mortgage payments as an example of what you cannot deduct.

Comment: Note that the info I have says that you cannot deduct mortgage interest, though you can deduct interest on loans to improve the rental property.

Comment: See [Form T776, Statement of Real Estate Rentals - Line 8710 - Interest](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/rntl/bt/rprt/xpns/ln8710-eng.html) .. quoting: *"You can deduct interest on money you borrow to **buy** or improve your rental property."*.  Bold emphasis mine. But I would expect the situation differs if the "property" one is renting out is part of one's own home. The case I'm assuming in my answer is a property that is strictly an investment/rental property and not claimed as principal residence by the owner. I think your link to turbotax.ca agrees with the CRA link I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. So if monthly principal is 800, interest + condo taxes (monthly) = 800, monthly maintenance = 300, and monthly rent = 1600, then profit = 1600 -800 - 300 = 500. And this 500 is taxed at marginal rate, is this true?

Comment: That may be simplistic. Determining the interest portion of your mortgage payments for a given tax year would require an amortization schedule or bank loan statements as the amounts vary as principal declines. You may also be omitting other deductible expenses, such as loan fees. See [Guide T4036 - Rental Income - Chapter 2 - Calculating your rental income or loss](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/t4036/t4036-e.html#P221_15825).

Comment: There is also the matter of expenses - painting the unit between tenants, any utilities the tenants don't cover, advertising the unit, etc. Plus of course condo fees. There is a worksheet at http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/rntl/bt/rprt/menu-eng.html that walks you through what is ok and what is not.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea you can deduct mortgage interest on your own home - the share of it that applies to the part rented - and I have done so. You can't deduct interest on a mortgage you took out for some other purpose like a vacation or to buy a cottage, just because you happen to have income from the mortgaged property.